# Sync folder in lightroom the opposite way

Tags: lightroom, delete, external

My normal workflow is:

go through pictures in library, hit X on the ones I want to delete.
Then hit command+Backspace to delete them all also from the disk.

Yesterday, I was working on the train on some pictures that I had back home on my external drive.
So I hit X on the ones I want to delete and then unfortunately hit command+Backspace.
So now the pictures are only gone in my library but not on the disk.

How can I delete them on the disk now? 
"Sync folder" just works the other way around (import those again to the catalog which I deleted).

Any ideas so that I have not do that all manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the deleted files are the only ones ‘missing’, they will be the only ones imported.

Import them again with ‘duplicate detection’ activated so that the only items imported are the ones you deleted.

Go to ‘recent imports’, select all and delete.